# TFT screen not working on Rpi A+

Tags: raspbian, spi, lcd

I have an old TFT LCD SPI screen, which I believe uses `ILI9341` and would like to use it on my (old) RPi A+. Unfortunately, it just stays blank. I am not even sure it is working...
My RPiA+ has a fresh *Raspbian* Stretch.

I have wired my screen following [this blog](https://marcosgildavid.blogspot.fr/2014/02/getting-ili9341-spi-screen-working-on.html) and using this [pin layout](http://www.raspberrysource.in.th/product/70/raspberry-pi-a). Just in case I haven't understood correctly:

- I have wired VIN of the screen to 3.3 VDC power on the Pi (pin 1)
- I **haven't wired MISO and SDCS**: my understanding is that they are for the SD card on the screen - which I do not use
- The LED is my case is wired to GPIO 2
- MOSI goes to "MOSI SPI GPIO 12"
- SCK goes to "SCLK SPI GPIO 14"
- CS goes to CE0 SPI GPIO 10
- D/C goes to GPIO 24
- RST goes to GPIO 25
- GND goes to ground

I tried to load the driver fb_ili9341, but this isn't supported:

```
$ sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:25,dc:24,led:2 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'fbtft_device': Invalid argument
```

I listed the available modules with `sudo modprobe fbtft_device name=list; dmesg | tail -30` and there was only one ili drivers: ili9481, so I decided to use that one (but I am not sure this is correct).

So, I tried again:

```
$ sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom width=320 height=240 name=ili9481 gpios=reset:25,dc:24,led:2,cs:10 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1
```

This **loads correctly** as we see in dmesg:

```
$ dmesg
...
 2229.934312] graphics fb1: fb_ili9481 frame buffer, 240x320, 150 KiB video memory, 4 KiB buffer memory, fps=20, spi0.0 at 16 MHz
[ 2229.934512] fbtft_device: GPIOS used by 'ili9481':
[ 2229.934524] fbtft_device: 'reset' = GPIO25
[ 2229.934530] fbtft_device: 'dc' = GPIO24
[ 2229.934536] fbtft_device: 'led' = GPIO2
[ 2229.934542] fbtft_device: 'cs' = GPIO10
[ 2229.934562] spidev spi0.1: spidev spi0.1 125000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
[ 2229.934578] fb_ili9481 spi0.0: fb_ili9481 spi0.0 16000kHz 8 bits mode=0x00
```

Then, according to the blog, I used `con2fbmap 1 1` to redirect the console to my screen. **It remains totally blank**.

Also, **I have enabled SPI** in raspi-config.

So my questions are:

1. Is my wiring correct?
2. Is the driver I am using correct, and if not,
   which one should I use. There is no specific indication on the
   device itself...
3. Is there a way to test if my screen is still
   working or damaged? SHould a LED be lighting up? (can't see one)
4. If it is functional, Why isn't it showing anything?

Thanks !

Comment: The correct command is `sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:25,dc:24,led:2 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1` in my case. The screen lights up, although nothing shows yet, but I think that's another issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were 2 issues:

1. The `Invalid argument` in my modprobe does not mean ili_9431 is not supported, but that my command has an invalid argument. **ili_9431 is supported**. It seems that the keyword `custom` is mandatory. So the right command should be `sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341...`
2. The GPIOs I used in my command line were wrong. To find the correct numbering of GPIOs for a given model of Raspberry Pi, I recommend using the command `pinout` which is from [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli_tools.html). In my case, the correct values were `gpios=reset:26,dc:19,led:27`.

So, the full command is: `sudo modprobe fbtft_device custom name=fb_ili9341 gpios=reset:26,dc:19,led:27 speed=16000000 rotate=90 bgr=1`. As soon as this command is launched the LED on the screen lights up.

Note that **fbtft_device** does not need to be downloaded or installed on current Raspbian versions, it's already there.